# LSTM one-step-ahead prediction with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am using Tensorflow's combination of `GRUCell` + `MultiRNNCell` + `dynamic_rnn` to generate a multi-layer LSTM to predict a sequence of elements.

In the few examples I have seen, like character-level language models, once the Training stage is done, the Generation seems to be done by feeding only ONE 'character' (or whatever element) at a time to get the next prediction, and then getting the following 'character' based on the first prediction, etc.

My question is, since Tensorflow's `dynamic_rnn` unrolls the RNN graph into an arbitrary number of steps of whatever sequence length is fed into it, what is the benefit of feeding only one element at a time, once a prediction is gradually being built out? Doesn't it make more sense to be gradually collecting a longer sequence with each predictive step and re-feeding it into the graph? I.e. after generating the first prediction, feed back a sequence of 2 elements, and then 3, etc.?

I am currently trying out the prediction stage by initially feeding in a sequence of 15 elements (actual historic data), getting the last element of the prediction, and then replacing one element in the original input with that predicted value, and so on in a loop of N predictive steps.

What is the disadvantage of this approach versus feeding just one element at-a-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your approach is actually doing what you want it to do.

Let's say we have an LSTM network trained to generate the alphabet. Now, in order to have the network generate a sequence, we start with a clean state `h0` and feed in the first character, `a`. The network outputs a new state, `h1`, and its prediction, `b`, which we append to our output. Next, we want the network to predict the next character based on the current output, `ab`. If we would feed the network `ab` with the state being `h1` at this step, its perceived sequence would be `aab`, because `h1` was calculated after the first `a`, and now we put in another `a` and a `b`. Alternatively, we could feed `ab` and a clean state `h0` into the network, which would provide a proper output (based on `ab`), but we would perform unnecessary calculations for the whole sequence except `b`, because we already calculated the state `h1` which corresponds to the network reading the sequence `a`, so in order to get the next prediction and state we only have to feed in the next character, `b`.

So to answer your question, feeding the network one character at a time makes sense because the network needs to see each character only once, and feeding the same character multiple times would just be unnecessary calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, makes sense! In this context, what would you think is the optimal way to 'warm up' the network before it starts to generate the predicted outputs. If I have a few data points of 'actual' observations, would it make sense to somehow warm-up the state first by going through those observations?

Comment: Yes absolutely. I wouldn't call this "warming up" the network, but rather generating text based on a starting sequence instead of a starting character, which is basically a seq2seq model. One example of this I've seen could be generating function code from the functions signature - first you feed in the individual characters of the signature, and then you generate the code one character at a time.

Comment: So you mean if you have, say, a starting sequence of 15 elements, then you feed in all 15 at once to generate the 16th element as the first prediction, and then from that prediction you continue one element at a time and reuse the state from the original pass of the 15-long sequence? Or do you iterate through the 15 elements one-by-one first? I guess it shouldn't matter either way?

Comment: Yep, doesn't matter, and yes, you feed in the 15 elements first, grab the output state and prediction and go one-by-one from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is an great question, I asked something very similar [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221513/why-are-the-weights-of-rnn-lstm-networks-shared-across-time).

The idea being instead of sharing weights across time (one element at-a-time as you describe it), each time step gets it's own set of weights.

I believe there are several reasons for training one-step at a time, mainly computational complexity and training difficulty. The number of weights you'll need to train grows linearly for each time step. You'd need some pretty sporty hardware to train long sequences. Also for long sequences you'll need a *very* large data set to train all those weights. But imho, I am still optimistic that for the right problem, with sufficient resources, it would show improvement.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at your other question. Just to clarify: I'm talking about GENERATING after training one-at-a-time versus in a sequence. (i.e. testing the already trained model). As far as the TRAINING itself, Im doing in long sequences, shifted by 1 to generate the Ys. You are right, lots of hardware requirements, but seems doable in the Cloud these days...